Register a new post status in WordPress Gutenberg
I'm trying to create a new post status of 'Archive' for old posts that I no longer want displayed, but don't want to delete them yet. I have tried registering the post status using the following:
function register_archived_post_status() {
    register_post_status('archived', array(
        'label'                     => _x('Archived', 'post'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop('Archived <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Archived <span class="count">(%s)</span>'),
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'register_archived_post_status');

However, I now need to be able to set posts to this status and I'm not seeing a new button/label to do so. Previously, post statuses were set in a dropdown, but it seems WP now displays them separately as buttons. I can see in documentation a note saying the functionality for adminstrative screen display of statuses is pending future development https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/post-status/ .
Can anyone point me in the right direction for this? Has anyone successfully done this with Gutenberg recently? Thank you.
Tried:
I've registered the status
function register_archived_post_status() {
    register_post_status('archived', array(
        'label'                     => _x('Archived', 'post'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop('Archived <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Archived <span class="count">(%s)</span>'),
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'register_archived_post_status');

However now I'm trying to create an administrative button for setting.

Have you read the documentation on this? "NOTICE: This function does NOT add the registered post status to the Administration Screen. This functionality is pending future development. Please refer to Trac Ticket #12706. Consider the action hook post_submitbox_misc_actions for adding this parameter."
